# What is the intuitive difference between $E(X 1_A)$ and $E(X|A)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I know that they are not the same since $E(X|A) = \frac{E(X 1_A)}{Pr(A)} $ (*)

But without using formula (*) above, for me, both of them means **"Average of X on an event A"**.

Could you please explain for me intuitively what is the subtle difference between $E(X 1_A)$ and $E(X|A)$?

Thank you.

Comment: $E(X|A)$ is *average* weight of $X$ on $A$. $E(X1_A)$ is *total* weight of $X$ on $A$.

Comment: @A.S. I get the "average of X on A" since expectation is kind of average in the long run. But could you please elaborate what "total" and "total weight of X on A" mean?

Comment: Imagine population of size $N$, let $X$ represent the weight of its members and let $A$ be the event that the person in question is a woman. Then $E(X|A)$ is an average weight of a woman - in other words total weight of women divided by number of women, while $E(X1_A)$ is total weight of women divided by total population. See the difference?